# Fatal Error Call to a member function getFormData() on a non-object

Tags: review, fatal-error

I am getting the following error in my website

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getFormData() on a non-object
>   in
>   /home/isafetyshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Form.php
>   on line 42

please have a look at `www.isafetyshop.com/` any product.

I am not able to find the reason for following error. Please help me, my coding knowledge is not good. I need assistance and I am ready to pay for service.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The line in question is this:

```
$data =  Mage::getSingleton('review/session')->getFormData(true);
```

This means that `Mage::getSingleton('review/session')` returns null (or false).
Check if you have the file `app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Session.php` exists.
If it doesn't then get it from a clean magento instance.
If the file is there, then most probably there is an extension overriding this model and there is no way to guess with the info you provided what's the problem.
You can investigate by following the [instructions in here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/428/146):